# Inline assembly-updating the free memory pointer

Tags: evm

When writing the inline assembly, is it coder's responsiblity to update the free memory pointer? or the EVM automatically updates it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the developer's responsibility.

By using (inline) assembly, you can take full control, obviously, that also means full responsibility.

Take this line from [the documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/assembly.html#memory-safety) :

> It is your responsibility to make sure that the assembly actually
> satisfies the memory model.